# ArrayOutOfBoundsException -1 while trying to implement BaumWelchLearner from Jahmm library

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception, hidden-markov-models

I am trying to create an HMM to predict chords based on played melodies in Java, using the Jahmm library [here](http://www.run.montefiore.ulg.ac.be/~francois/software/jahmm). I am following along with the example that they provide on their page, though I made several changes. For my purposes all I need is the following:

```
Hmm<ObservationInteger> learntHmm = buildInitHmm();

List<List<ObservationInteger>> sequences = generateSequences();
BaumWelchLearner learner = new BaumWelchLearner();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    learntHmm = learner.iterate(learntHmm, sequences);
}
```

The initial HMM I have basically everything set to (1/7), for the 7 chords and 7 notes in a key.

My `generateSequences()` method is the following:

```
List<List<ObservationInteger>> sequences = new ArrayList<List<ObservationInteger>>();

try {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("trainingData.txt")));
    String currentLine;
    Random generator = new Random();
    while ((currentLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        String data[] = currentLine.split(" ");
        List<ObservationInteger> observations = new ArrayList<ObservationInteger>();
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            int dataValue = ((Integer.parseInt(data[i])) % 7);
            ObservationInteger observationInteger = new ObservationInteger(dataValue);
            observations.add(observationInteger);
        }
        sequences.add(observations);
    }
    bufferedReader.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("File not found.");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return sequences;
```

This reads the values from a .txt file into the `List<List<ObservationInteger>>` that is then used to learn the HMM. However, if I run this, I get a `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1` on the line `learntHmm = learner.iterate(learntHmm, sequences);`.

Fair enough, however when I change this

```
ObservationInteger observationInteger = new ObservationInteger(dataValue)
```

to instead be

```
ObservationInteger(Random.nextInt(7))
```

this works perfectly fine. I don't understand why this would be the case: in both of these cases I am providing the `sequences` with observations valued as integers between 0-6. In both cases the dimensions are exactly the same, but only when the integers are randomly generated instead of read in from my file does this work. Any ideas why?

[Observation Integer Class](http://www.run.montefiore.ulg.ac.be/~francois/software/jahmm/doc/jahmm-0.6.1-javadoc/)

Full Stack Trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at be.ac.ulg.montefiore.run.jahmm.OpdfInteger.probability(OpdfInteger.java:85)
at be.ac.ulg.montefiore.run.jahmm.OpdfInteger.probability(OpdfInteger.java:1)
at be.ac.ulg.montefiore.run.jahmm.ForwardBackwardCalculator.computeAlphaStep(ForwardBackwardCalculator.java:124)
at be.ac.ulg.montefiore.run.jahmm.ForwardBackwardCalculator.computeAlpha(ForwardBackwardCalculator.java:102)
at be.ac.ulg.montefiore.run.jahmm.ForwardBackwardCalculator.<init>(ForwardBackwardCalculator.java:63)
at be.ac.ulg.montefiore.run.jahmm.learn.BaumWelchLearner.generateForwardBackwardCalculator(BaumWelchLearner.java:133)
at be.ac.ulg.montefiore.run.jahmm.learn.BaumWelchLearner.iterate(BaumWelchLearner.java:73)
at HiddenMarkovModel.main(HiddenMarkovModel.java:30)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Comment: http://www.run.montefiore.ulg.ac.be/~francois/software/jahmm/doc/jahmm-0.6.1-javadoc/

Comment: could you show us full stacktrace?

Comment: could paste also "trainingData.txt" file?

Comment: Seems like some of the `observations` or the `sequences` list is empty. Debug through your code to spot the empty collection.

Comment: I did a quick sysout to print `dataValue` each time, it seems that -1 shows up. Values need to be 0-6. But I am doing dataValue = integer % 7, so why would -1 occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone pointed out, some of the values being read into the sequences were not properly valued. For this set up to work HMM needed to take values between 0-6. I am not entirely sure why modulo did not account for this, but I wrote my own little method that guaranteed all values read in from .txt file were between 0 and 6 and that fixed it.